# VLOOKUP with button click

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to write some code for a button click to perform a VLOOKUP.

Sheet1 = Payment Form, Sheet2 = Global, Sheet3 = Details

Button will be on Sheet "Payment Form".

This would be the code for Cells in Global Sheet,

O1 = `=VLOOKUP(BA,Details!A:H,8,0)`
P1 = `=VLOOKUP(BA,Details!A:H,6,0)`
Q1 =`VLOOKUP(BA,Details!A:H,5,0)`

I need this to loop through all rows as the amount can change each month, if a match is found the perform the VlookUp, is no match is found, the delete the row from the Details Sheet.

For Example: Global, Cell B1 = 27801. In Details match found, then do the above codes from Columns O, P & Q.
Global, B2 = 27802. In Details no matching record found, row deleted. Continue to row 3 & 4 ......

Comment: What have you done in VBA so far?

Comment: @Sam Hi, i have nothing to the moment i don't know where to start, im still very new to VBA

Comment: Try recording a macro and see what code do you come up with?

Comment: `Application.VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, column_index, range_lookup)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout, this is the code it come out with, i need it loop through all rows.     Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-13],Details!C[-14]:C[-7],8,0)"
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-14],Details!C[-15]:C[-8],6,0)"
    Range("Q1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-15],Details!C[-16]:C[-9],5,0)"
    Range("Q2").Select

Comment: Have a look at http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html I would use a for loop. You will need to create a variable to get the last cell range and use that as the end value for the for loop

Comment: @Sam I have looked at the link and have looked through google for answers, but can not figure anything out. I have no idea how to do this! Please help!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what I suggest is you put all the value in table will be more efficient (not simply enter in the excel cell), you need create the table by INSERT ->Table. It will look like this :
 [image: global table]

 Do this also for the Details :
[image: Details table]

 Back to global worksheet, just need enter 1 row of formula, the rest of the rows in the same column will have the same formula "style" 

Column O :=VLOOKUP([Column BA],Table2[[#All],[Column1]:[Column8]],8,FALSE)

Column P :=VLOOKUP([Column BA],Details!A:H,6,FALSE)

Column Q :=VLOOKUP([Column BA],Details!A:H,5,FALSE)

To remove the unwanted row, just filter out the blanks value in that columns will do.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i need it to happen on a button click. Basically the user will paste new data each month into Global and Details, when click a button that will do the VLookUps Automatically

Comment: VLookup will be done automatically in the table after creating for the 1st time. In addition, if the user keep on pump in the data at details worksheet, the VLookup will auto generate the result at global worksheet. So we don't need have a button to create the VLookup formula again.

Comment: would it be easier to use a find loop, so find data in column b, then if match, copy columns H,F & E to O, P & Q

Comment: VLookup already perform all the requirement you need, Let take this example Column P:=VLOOKUP([Column BA],Details!A:H,6,FALSE)  , It will search column BA at Details worksheet column A until H follow by copy the value of H at Details worksheet to column P if exactly match (set by FALSE) is found.So, for your case, you don't need write the macro but put the data in table(with headers) and put formula for the 1st data row. Here got more explanation about VLookup, hope it clear your doubts [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617441/create-a-vba-macro-that-find-and-copy/30618397#30618397)