# Create a VBA macro that Find and Copy?

Tags: vba, excel

I need a little bit help with a macro of Excel.

I need to create a macro that automatically find users and copy the values that i have in an other Sheet:

I have one sheet with values that contains the Users and their Kills and Deaths, I create 3 sheets more (3 different groups of users), and I need that the macro copy values automatically finding the users and copying values.

[image]

Images to describe it better:

[image]

----(Copy this values on)----->

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a macro for this, using the worksheetfunction [`VLOOKUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701.aspx) is sufficient.

As an example, if you have your headers in row 1 and users in column A, what you'd put into cell B2 (the number of kills for the first user) would be `=VLOOKUP($A2;Values!$A$2:$C$9;2;FALSE)` and C2 would be `=VLOOKUP($A2;Values!$A$2:$C$9;3;FALSE)`.

The arguments for the function (which you can also find in the linked document) is:

- First, the value you're looking for, in your case whatever is in A2
- Next the array of values which you want to return a result from - `vlookup` will only look through the first column, but since you want to return results from the other columns we include columns A:C in the formula.
- What column in the range you search to return the result from for kills it is column 2, for deaths column 3.
- Finally whether you want to have an exact match (`false`) or if an approximate one is ok (`true`).

Comment: My real values are too big to do it with a fuction, can I show you the real excel and you can help me with it? Would be nice

Comment: I very much doubt that you can set up a macro which works faster than native Excel functions for replicating values. At the very least the task you were trying to accomplish would have to be significantly more complicated than this. @GonzaloPaniagua

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're after, you should be able to do this with [VLOOKUPs](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/lookup-reference-functions.html)

(No VBA necessary)

Comment: This values are not real, i need a macro because i get new values every day and i work with a lot of data, so i need a work with a vba, would be easy do it every day with only  one key

Comment: But if you set up the vlookups, and providing the user list doesn't change, they will automatically update everyday correctly after you put in the new values in the first sheet.

Answer (score 1):

The following source code solve your problem.

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyResultWorkbook As Workbook
Dim ValuesWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim SniperWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim ARsWorksheet As Worksheet

Sub CopyResult()
Set MyResultWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set ValuesWorksheet = MyResultWorkbook.Sheets("Values")
Set SniperWorksheet = MyResultWorkbook.Sheets("Sniper")
Set ARsWorksheet = MyResultWorkbook.Sheets("Ars")

Dim SniperLastRow As Long
Dim ARLastRow As Long
Dim RowPointer As Long
Dim ValuePointer As Long

ValuePointer = 2

'Update the Sniper worksheets
SniperLastRow = SniperWorksheet.Cells(SniperWorksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For RowPointer = 2 To SniperLastRow

Do While (SniperWorksheet.Range("A" & RowPointer).Value <> ValuesWorksheet.Range("A" & ValuePointer).Value)
    ValuePointer = ValuePointer + 1
Loop
SniperWorksheet.Range("A" & RowPointer).Offset(0, 1).Value = ValuesWorksheet.Range("A" & ValuePointer).Offset(0, 1).Value 'copy kill
SniperWorksheet.Range("A" & RowPointer).Offset(0, 2).Value = ValuesWorksheet.Range("A" & ValuePointer).Offset(0, 2).Value 'copy death
ValuePointer = 2
Next

'Update the Ars worksheets
ARLastRow = ARsWorksheet.Cells(ARsWorksheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For RowPointer = 2 To ARLastRow

Do While (ARsWorksheet.Range("A" & RowPointer).Value <> ValuesWorksheet.Range("A" & ValuePointer).Value)
    ValuePointer = ValuePointer + 1
Loop
ARsWorksheet.Range("A" & RowPointer).Offset(0, 1).Value = ValuesWorksheet.Range("A" & ValuePointer).Offset(0, 1).Value 'copy kill
ARsWorksheet.Range("A" & RowPointer).Offset(0, 2).Value = ValuesWorksheet.Range("A" & ValuePointer).Offset(0, 2).Value 'copy death
ValuePointer = 2
Next

End Sub
```